# Complexity of the problem to determine if a spanning tree exists inside a connected graph

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs

Given a connected graph G, what is the complexity of the problem to determine if a spanning tree with a number of leaves less or equal to k exists inside G? I don't really know how to determine it and how to reach a proper solution to this.

Comment: Hint: consider the case $k=2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $k = 2$, this is just the Hamiltonian path problem, which is known to be NP-complete.

Comment: So the complexity is something like O(n^2)?